# tt_news detail page not working after switch frontend language. error shows "no news_id given"

Tags: tt-news

- I have problem with tt_news detail page. On news detail page language
  switch is not working shows error in front end 'no news-id given'.

Comment: I got solution . Have to add addQueryString = 1 in language menu.15 = HMENU
15.wrap = <ul class="lang">|</ul>
15 {
  special = language
  special.value = 0,1
  addQueryString = 1 }

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not get parameter in language icon

for add parameter you just have to add **addQueryString** in language typo script

Following example will help you more.

```
stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString = 1
```

You may refer following link for typoscript of language menu 
https://jainishsenjaliya.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/language-menu-via-typoscript/